# How to use react navigation in cljs?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, clojurescript

Here’s my code in which I’m trying to create multiple bottom tabs using react navigation

```
(defn sample-comp []
[:> View [:> Text "Sample Container!"]])
(defn root-comp []
  [:> NavigationContainer
   [:> SafeAreaView
    (let [Tab (createBottomTabNavigator)]
      [:> (.-Navigator Tab)
       [:> (.-Screen Tab)
        {:name "Home"
         :component (r/reactify-component sample-comp)}]])]])
(defn init []
  ;; register error also occurs if there's a non-
  ;; related error in the code
  (dispatch [:register-db])
  (render-root "Humboi" (r/as-element [root-comp])))
```

but I’m getting the following error:
requireNativeComponent: “RNCSafeAreaProvider” was not found in UIManager.
How to fix this error?